# How to destroy YUI Panel on close?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui

I want to be able to destroy a YUI Panel when the user clicks the close button.

I have tried using `hideEvent` but that does not work.  I'm assuming since the object is still active and therefore cannot be destroyed:

```
panel.hideEvent.subscribe(function(o) {
    panel.destroy();
});
```

Is there a way I can destroy the Panel when a user clicks close?  The close button is not assigned an ID although it is assigned a class:

```
<a class="container-close" href="#">Close</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ending up having to use the setTimeout() function:

```
panel.hideEvent.subscribe(function(o) {
    setTimeout(function() {panel.destroy();}, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where win is a YUI simple dialog, I use this:

```
w.win.hideEvent.subscribe(function(e) {
                                                    this.destroy();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

using the hideEvent as above leads to javascript errors in firebug. the following solution works without problems:

dlg -> instance of yui2 dialog or similar.
dlg.close -> is the html element of the close icon

Use the following code after having the dialog rendered:

```
//remove the default click handler (._doClose)
YAHOO.util.Event.removeListener(dlg.close, "click");   

//add a new click handler (._doClose)
YAHOO.util.Event.on(dlg.close, "click", function(){
    this.destroy();
}, dlg, true);
```